# How to run iOS app in iPhone without USB connection to Mac

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-app-group

I have developed my first apple app and i wish to run it in iphone (its working well in `XCode`). By running in `iphone` i don't mean to connect it with mac and run with USB connection.

I mean something like there will be `uuid` of iphone and i upload my app some where and it can be run by Iphone user without any wire-connection to my MAC where i have app in xcode.

Is it possible to achieve by anyway? **Is that way to achieve is free of cost ?**

Comment: If you want to run it locally and debug check out http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/206130

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I understand from you question is you want to distribute your application to others,

If you have apple developers account , you can use TestFlight [ITunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/itc/static/login?view=1&path=%2FWebObjects%2FiTunesConnect.woa%3F), where you can distribute upto 1000 users

Or you could use other free providers like,

1. [Fabric](https://get.fabric.io/)
2. [Hockey](http://hockeyapp.net)

I personally recommend Fabric , it's free, has lot of features

Comment: is the apple developers account free of cost ?

Comment: It's not free, $100 per year , but when you want to submit your app to AppStore you must have an developer account

Comment: So the only cheapest way  for students is to use fabric and Hockey ...right ? But what is the process after if i choose lets say "Fabric" ?

Comment: Please visit the fabric website to understand how to get started , they have pretty good documentation

Answer (score 3):

In your project set your ***distribution profiles in code signing options***
Then click on **product-->Build** wait for a moment until it opens an **Organizer window** .

After opening organizer window **select save for AdHoC deployment --> choose your organization--> select for all devices compatibility(if you are running with latest Xcode 7.3 version *otherwise devices compatibility window won't appear*)** click next next.

Finally you can get an **api file** in the Organizer window. In that select the first api file which has recently you built -> click on export to your any finder location.

Then open your api file location in your Finder.

Then open your browser and open https://www.diawi.com and **drag and drop** your api in the specified field and wait until it reaches 100% to upload and click on send so that you can get a link. Now you can share your link.

*Note: In iOS device he can install the api by using safari browser with the link we have shared*

Comment: Please give right answer if My answer satisfied your question @test test and NicolasMiari